# Cannot browserify the backbone-syphon

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, sails.js, browserify, browserify-shim

This is my first time using browserify. I am trying to use the backbone-syphon library (https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.syphon) in my sails.js/Gulp/Browserify/Backbone project.

My package.json has this

```
"browser": {
        "backbone.syphon": "./assets/js/lib/backbone-syphon/backbone.syphon.js",
        "bootstrap": "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
        "jQuery": "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
},
"browserify": {
        "transform": [
            "browserify-shim"
        ]
},
"browserify-shim": {
        "bootstrap": {
            "exports": "bootstrap",
            "depends": [
                "jquery:jQuery"
            ]
        },
        "backbone.syphon": {
            "exports": "Backbone.Syphon",
            "depends": [
                //"backbone:Backbone" //Tried only this also
                "backbone:Backbone", "jquery:jQuery", "underscore:_"
            ]
        }
},
```

I do not get any errors during startup. But when I try to use "Backbone.Syphon" anywhere in the code it gives an undefined error.

I have explicitly added `require('lib/backbone-syphon/backbone.syphon.js')` in my code though I am not sure if that is necessary or not.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Using the latest syphon library works correctly with browserify. Not sure why the old one was not working.

Should have tried this before posting the question.